# Is possible to show notification on apple watch without iPhone?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am working on just apple watch app and I would like to send notification to user on specific time. But I can't find anywhere how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to send a local notification from the Watch Extension's code.

Set up the `UNUserNotificationCenter` in your `Watch App`, then call `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)` anywhere in your Watch's code and you will receive the local notification on the Watch.